# How can I use CAD ground plane in PHP web application in order to calculate distances between points?

Tags: javascript, php, web, cad

I have an Autocad Warehouse ground plane which I want to read on my PHP based web application in order to calculate exact distances between points (not airline distance) which are actually storage slots in warehouse.

Is there any platform/framework/script which can help me?

Any ideas, advices? Thanks in advance.